# How to confirm transaction as a receiver in metamask?

Tags: solidity, metamask

My question is simple
If I want to send some ether to someone in remix like

```
contract Sender {
  function send(address _receiver) payable {
    _receiver.send(msg.value);
  }
}
```

- Metamask asks me as a sender to confirm the transaction and thus
  simply send the amount to receiver without even asking him/her.

**How can I make receiver accept the transaction ?**

Answer (score 1):

As long as the receiver is a payable address (i.e. a regular Ethereum account or a smart contract with a payable fallback function), they will automatically accept it.

Why do you think the receiver would not accept it, or what use case would there be for a receiver to reject a transaction?

Comment: Is it not true both receiver and sender sign the transaction first to be recorded in blockchain ?

Comment: No, only the sender signs the transaction, there is no reason for the receiver to sign as it has nothing to prove.